# Mulitple users and passwords javascript login

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

Don´t know if this is possibly, i am new to js, so keep that in mind.
I want to have mulitple passwords and multiple user names in my little form. The javascript code is:

```
var attempt = 3; 
function validate(){
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
if ( username == "root" && password == "root"){ // here is password and username
sweetAlert ("Login successfully");
window.location = "success.html"; 
return false;
}
else{
attempt --;// Decrementing by one.
sweetAlert("You have  "+attempt+" attempt(s) left.");
// Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
if( attempt == 0){
sweetAlert("Oops...", "You have failed  to log in 3 times, Fields have been turned off. Please try again later", "error");
document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: You are aware this is incredibly poor security? Anyone can read your JS code, even on  your production website. Even when your code is minified, people can still read your usernames and passwords from the code.

Comment: This is no security. Bin it

Comment: Yes, i am perfectly aware of this, it is only there to stop "regular" people from getting confused by the unfinished page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved with an `else if` statement.

```
if ( username == "root" && password == "root") {
    // login user 1
}
else if( username == "username2" && password == "password2") {
    // login user 2
}
else {
    // reject
}
```

Keep in mind that (as this appears to be running locally on the user's browser) it would be trivial for a user to edit the code directly on the page to accept any login they choose. Look in to accepting the user's credentials on the server, where only you can choose which username and password work.

Comment: Thank you! Would i need to use php for this? For now i don't want to need a web server as the complete page is just for a friend.

Comment: There are a ton of languages you could use; PHP with Apache is pretty common. If you're interested in improving your JavaScript skills, you can try setting up a server with Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a Map to store the logins and passwords. It is more manageable than using `if` statements as each login would mean a change to your logic.

```js
let
  attempts = 3,
  logins = new Map([
    ['root', 'root'],
    ['admin', 'admin']
  ]);
  formElement = document.getElementById('form');

function disableForm() {
  const
    usernameInput = document.getElementById('username'),
    passwordInput = document.getElementById('password'),
    submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');

  usernameInput.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  passwordInput.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  submitButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');  
}

function decreaseAttemptsLeft() {
  // Decrease attempts by 1.
  attempts--;
  
  // Check if attempts is 0...
  if (attempts === 0) {
    // ... and disable the form controls.
    disableForm();
    // ... and show the user a message.
    alert('You have failed  to log in 3 times, Fields have been turned off. Please try again later');
  } else {
    // Show a message with login attempts left.
    const
      message = `You have ${attempts} attempt(s) left.`;
    alert(message);  
  }
}

function onFormSubmit(event){
  // prevent the actual form submission.
  event.preventDefault();
  
  const
    usernameInput = document.getElementById('username'),
    passwordInput = document.getElementById('password');
  
  if (
    // When the logins map doesn't have a key for the username OR
    !logins.has(usernameInput.value) ||
    // The password doesn't match the value for the user name
    logins.get(usernameInput.value) !== passwordInput.value
  ) {
    // Decrease the number of attempts left.
    decreaseAttemptsLeft();
    // Exit the method.
    return;
  }
  
  // Show the success message.
  alert('Login success!');
  // Reset the attempts counter.
  attempts = 3;
}
  
form.addEventListener('submit', onFormSubmit);
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label>
    Username:
    <input type="text" id="username"/>
  </label>
  <label>
    Password:
    <input type="password" id="password"/>
  </label>
  
  <button id="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Just to be abundantly clear: this is EXTREMELY poor security. Do not do this for anything other than fooling your kid sister/brother.

Comment: Ahah cheers mate! Is there a limit to how many i can add with this type of code before it becomes slow/ Unusable? As mention above, yes i know js logins are really really bad security wise. But its only to stop "Regular people" from getting confused while its being built

Comment: There is virtually no limit. You can add as many as needed and there is no need to change the logic to validate the logins.